# With <rich:tabPanel>, some times on tab change, two ajax requests are being sent to server instead of one

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have an application running in production. Some times when clicked on tab to switch, observed that instead of 1 ajax request, 2 ajax requests are being fired.

1) First ajax went through the JSF life cycle and loaded the data by calling the itemChangeListener method(dataBean.tabChangeListener) for tab and rendered in browser.

2) Second ajax request fired internally from browser without any user action. Observed that in this second request also, jsf life cycle executed successfully. But here tab change listener method not executed.

It looks like strange behavior. Why its firing 2 ajax requests instead of one ?. We have used jstl,facelets tags as well in the code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have tired by enabling the `<a4j:log/>` in the jsf file to check the ajax events logs.

Even checked in the browser network tab by filtering the xhr(ajax) request types.

[image: browser network activity debug]

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax" id="tabPanel" 
                    itemChangeListener="#{dataBean.tabChangeListener}" >
```

Expected is only one ajax request should be fired on click of tab change.
but actually here its firing 2 ajax requests.

Comment: You can inspect both POST request to figure out which exact component triggered it: Klick on the request -> Switch to Parameters tab -> find `javax.faces.source` parameter posted.

Comment: @Selaron, thanks for your reply. ```javax.faces.source``` is showing same client id(particular tab id).

Comment: Maybe the enduser did a doubleclick on a tab header? Did you try that?

Comment: @Kukeltje, thanks for your comment. But here its not double click on tab header. Two ajax requests going for single Click only.

Comment: Without knowing what the requests contain or where they came from there's not much we can help with. The requests are sent by `jsf.ajax.request`, check what methods are calling it.